# SharePoint 2013 :- Web Application taking forever to create

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint 2013 installation on a Window 8 machine.
I am trying to create a web application and it is taking forever. The creation process never stops. I checked in application event logs and found this error:

*Machine 'SHAREPOINT2013C (SharePoint - 43000(_LM_W3SVC_1458308317_ROOT))' failed ping validation and has been unavailable since '1/22/2013 3:56:48 AM'.*

Searched the web but could not find anything that works for me.
Can anyone suggest a way to resolve the issue? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: How did you manage to install SharePoint 2013 in Windows 8, if SharePoint 2013 requires Server OS (Windows Server2008/2012)?

Answer (score 1):

Below are my findings:

In order to recognize routing targets IIS has to be able to process SPPING HTTP method

To test run this code in Powershell:

```
    $url = "http://your-Routing-Target-Server-Name"
    $myReq = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($url)
    $myReq.Method = "SPPING";
    $response = $myReq.GetResponse();
    $response.StatusCode
```

If you get the following error message:
Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed."
that means that web front end is not set up to process SPPING HTTP method

To resolve the issue run the following commands on each routing target server:

```
    Import-Module WebAdministration
    add-WebConfiguration /system.webserver/handlers "IIS:\" -value @{
        name =          "SPPINGVerbHandler"
        verb =          "SPPING"
        path =          "*"
        modules =       "ProtocolSupportModule"
        requireAccess = "None"
    }
```

This will add a handler for SPPING verb to IIS configuration.

Run the test script again to make sure this works.

Answer (score 0):

So this has to do with the Request Management Service that runs on the WFE servers on SharePoint 2013.  The Request Management Service is of no value since you only have one server.  If you disable this service on your single server farm these messages will go away and your Web Application creation performance will greatly increase.

Mark Ringo

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced this issue, I created new Web Application and it was showing a popup of "It shouldn't take long", then after some time it showed a Connection failure page. I browsed to the virtual directory folder for the new web application and found that the folder was totally empty.

Then what I did to solve this problem:

```
1. Open IIS
2. Go to Applicatin Pools
3. Select Central Admin application pool and right click and select "Advance Settings".
4. There was a property named "Shutdown Time Limit", it was set to "90" by default. I changed it to 400 and clicked OK.
```

It restarted the applicaition pool automatically. Then again I created new web application from central admin and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that these events correlate to when the specified application pools are recycled (mine are at a specific time in the morning).  It's unfortunate that they're logged in the event viewer and can't really clean it up.